# Ruby On Rails, write script based on time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, time

I want to write a script that will reset the guest user's data in my database every 24 hours. I'm not sure how to go about doing this; my first thought was using Time.now, but how would I calculate the time difference?

Comment: what time difference you are talking about?  You need to run the script once  a day. You need cron - https://elements.heroku.com/addons/scheduler

Comment: Are you wanting know how to write a script that will run every 24 hours OR how to query the last 24 hours of data?

Comment: @user3366016 I want to know how to write a script that will run every 24 hours.

Comment: In that case you need to look at cron jobs that can be set to run code (a task) at a predefined interval (i.e. every 24 hours).  Read this tutorial on scheduling tasks in rails https://launchschool.com/blog/cron-jobs-and-rails.  Also read this documentation on rails tasks. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html.  you will likely want to write a task that is run through a cron job.  There are gems to help with this but youll have read up on the concept first. https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/scheduling

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking about how to query the previous 24 hours data.

Like this,

```
@records = YourModelName.where(created_at: (Time.now - 24.hours)..Time.now)
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm looking to learn how to write a script that will run every 24 hours.